# Swift: Why is IBAction crashing app when I seem to have a reference to variable in separate UITableViewController?

Tags: uitableview, swift, iboutlet

I have a custom UITableViewCell class named PinCell.swift which contains a reference to a UITableViewController and an IBAction that passes data from the cell to the UITableViewController. I have no errors and everything builds fine.

**PinCell.swift (UITableViewCell):**

```
    var viewControllerB:UITableViewController!

    @IBAction func titleButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var venueIDFromRequest = self.pin?["venue"]["id"].stringValue
    println("venueIDFromRequest is: \(venueIDFromRequest)")
    if venueIDFromRequest != nil {
        let venueDetailRef = viewControllerB as! VenueDetailViewController
        venueDetailRef.venueIDPassed = venueIDFromRequest!
    }
    if(self.delegate != nil){ //Just to be safe.
        self.delegate.callSegueFromCell(venueIDFromRequest: venueIDFromRequest!)
    }
}
```

**VenueDetailViewController.swift (UITableViewController)**

```
var venueIDPassed:String! = "asdklasdkas"
```

When I tap the button in my app, it crashes and the following is printed out to the console `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` which we have all seen before and I realize what this error means. My question is why is this happening when it seems to have a reference to the variable in the other view controller? Even when I `println(venueIDFromRequest)` I get the correct data. What am I doing wrong here and how can I assign `venueIDFromRequest` to `self.viewControllerB.venueIDPassed` ?

Here is a screenshot if it can help diagnose what is actually going on:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the outlet is disconnected.

Comment: How can I connect it to reference VenueDetailViewController?

Comment: In the same way you connected it in the first place.  I was going to write an answer... but I'm not sure how you even connect a view **controller** with an outlet.

Comment: @nhgrif Ok I removed the IBOutlet altogether and replaced it with the property `var viewControllerB:UITableViewController!`. Then inside `titleButtonPressed` I do `let venueDetailRef = viewControllerB as! VenueDetailViewController
        venueDetailRef.venueIDPassed = venueIDFromRequest!` and still get the same error I had before.